# Firefox push notifications - Payload NodeJS Buffer To PHP

Tags: node.js, push-notification, push, service-worker, payload

For a specific project I'm using on a first server the [web-push library from marco-c](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push).
On a second server I have a PHP script which allows to send notifications to the endpoint URL via a simple POST request.

Since the payload is now used by Firefox and Google I wanted to develop a way to :

1. Send the payload from 2nd server (PHP) to 1st server (NodeJS)
2. Encrypt the payload on the 1st server (NodeJS)
3. Return the encrypted payload from 1st server to 2nd server (PHP)
4. Send the notification with the encrypted payload from 2nd server (PHP) to the browser endpoint.

Problem : marco-c library returns the encrypted payload as NodeJS Buffer and I don't have any idea about how to get this data and "transform" it to be able to send this with the curl function for example (or fsockopen).

Here is how the code is returned by the NodeJS server :

```js
var tempVar = encrypt(user_p256dh, user_auth, message);
decodedData.encryptedData = tempVar.cipherText;
decodedData.Key = tempVar.key;
decodedData.Salt = tempVar.salt;
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(decodedData).length});
res.end(JSON.stringify(decodedData));
```

then this is read via PHP Script and here is how the request to the endpoint is created :

```html
$fsockParameter = "POST /wpush/v1/USER_ENDPOINT HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$fsockParameter .= "Host: updates.push.services.mozilla.com\r\n";
$fsockParameter .= "Content-Encoding: aesgcm\r\n";
$fsockParameter .= "Encryption: keyid=p256dh;salt=SALTVAR_INSERTED_HERE\r\n";
$fsockParameter .= "Crypto-key: keyid=p256dh;dh=DHVAR_INSERTED_HERE\r\n";
$fsockParameter .= "TTL: 60\r\n";
$fsockParameter .= "Content-Length: ENCRYPTED_DATA_SIZE\r\n\r\n";
$fsockParameter .= ENCRYPTED_DATA;
```

I know that this is not simple but at the moment I must use this configuration (1st and 2nd server) and I really need to find a solution for this.

Thanks for helping me ..!

Comment: As a solution, I found that I can use this by returning the cipherText via this code line : 

decodedData.encryptedData = tempVar.cipherText.toString('base64');

Then get this value via my PHP server and send this as ENCRYPTED_DATA. This is working with Chrome endpoint but not with Firefox as it seems to accept only NodeJS Buffer..

Comment: You could base64-encode the data in the Node.js server and in the PHP server remove the line `$fsockParameter .= ENCRYPTED_DATA;`, and do something like `fwrite($fp, $fsockParameter); fwrite($fp, base64_decode(ENCRYPTED_DATA);`.

Comment: Hi Marco and thanks for your help. This is really appreciated. 

This is a good idea and I tested it but I may be missing something as I still get a Firefox Error :  
"OperationError: The operation failed for an operation-specific reason"

Is there any solution to debug this and see the Payload received on the endpoint then check what is the problem between the payload sent and the payload received by the endpoint ? 

Many thanks for your help, you guys are awesome !

Comment: There might be some mismatch between the base64 encoding used in Node.js and in PHP, or maybe something is going wrong when you transmit this data from the Node.js server to the PHP one. A simple thing that you could do is comparing the Node.js buffer (tempVar.cipherText) with the result of base64_decode.